# spark sql error when reading data from Avro Table

Tags: apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

When I try reading data from an avro table using spark-sql, I am getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.supportedCategories(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspectorWorker(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.createObjectInspector(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.<init>(AvroObjectInspectorGenerator.java:56)
```

This is my sbt file

```
val sparkVersion = "2.4.2"

libraryDependencies ++=  Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "4.0.0"
```

Do I need to add any dependencies? THe code works fine in hive, but spark is having issues.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: please try with 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % "2.4.0"

Comment: Hello @dassum, I tried this and it seems fine. But Now I am getting this error. Caused by: MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class  not found)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:442)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Partition.getDeserializer(Partition.java:250)

Comment: You need to always use dependency versions that match your Spark version. Change it to 2.4.2 or reuse your variable

Comment: @cricket_007, I tried with pyspark --driver-memory 10g --jars /tmp/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.2.jar still getting the same error. It is happening when I am trying to join a table's data with the avro schema. Trying to see if a simple filter does it too.

Comment: You shouldn't need Spark avro if you're reading avro data from Hive anyway since Hive server handles that translation. Have you tried using any other tool to query the same table?

Comment: Yes querying the table with hive works fine.